# How to enlarge spacing between lines (change baselineskip) in beamer?

Tags: beamer, line-spacing, article, line

I want spacing between lines larger in my beamer. I used to type:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
```

but this seems not working in beamer

Answer (score 1):

Spacing between lines in `beamer` presentations can be increased on the same way as at other documents (`article`, `report`, ...). For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace}  % <---
\setstretch{1.5}       % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[66]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

If you remove marked code lines inabove MWE, result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
```

the same way as at other documents (article, report, ...).

Another solution which do not need a new package